# Openshift app not responding

Tags: django, openshift, connection-timeout

I have a work in progress django app hosted on openshift, at some point over the last few days it has stopped responding entirely in the browser.

I can still ssh into it, I can deploy to it, and the openshift.redhat.com interface isn't reporting any errors with the app, but requesting any page through the browser just doesn't give any response. Browser just keeps saying "Waiting for appname-user.rhcloud.com".

The logs might provide some insight.

```
rhc tail appname
==> app-root/logs/python.log <==
Unable to open logs
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.8.172.129:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.8.172.129:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
... (ad infinitum)
```

I don't think it stopped responding after a deploy, it was working, then it wasn't. No idea what happened.

Would appreciate any ideas to what could cause this or how to debug / resolve it.

---

## EDIT

Based on fat fantasma's suggestion I tried a force-stop/start cycle and this what was logged:

```
$ rhc app force-stop -a notebook
$ rhc app start -a notebook

$ rhc tail notebook
==> app-root/logs/python.log <==
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.8.172.129:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.8.172.129:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
[Sun Nov 16 01:26:13 2014] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c4,c359
[Sun Nov 16 01:26:13 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Nov 16 01:26:13 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Nov 16 01:26:13 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations

==> app-root/logs/postgresql.log <==
2014-11-16 06:26:05 GMT LOG:  trying another address for the statistics collector
2014-11-16 06:26:05 GMT LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Cannot assign requested address
2014-11-16 06:26:05 GMT LOG:  disabling statistics collector for lack of working socket
2014-11-16 06:26:05 GMT WARNING:  autovacuum not started because of misconfiguration
2014-11-16 06:26:05 GMT HINT:  Enable the "track_counts" option.
2014-11-16 06:26:06 GMT LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2014-11-15 07:33:35 GMT
2014-11-16 06:26:06 GMT LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2014-11-16 06:26:06 GMT LOG:  record with zero length at 0/1D48850
2014-11-16 06:26:06 GMT LOG:  redo is not required
2014-11-16 06:26:06 GMT LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

I could be wrong, but I still have this feeling the app is fine, it could be something DNS related. I tried a DNS trace of my app URL (http://notebook-davur.rhcloud.com) and the trace ends with this nugget:

```
Sending request to "ns3.p23.dynect.net" (208.78.71.23)
Received authoritative (AA) response:
-> Header: Non-Existent Domain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fairly sure this wasn't a code issue as the problem didn't start right after deploying any changes. To verify that the problem wasn't with the code, I created a new app and pushed the same code to it.

```
$ rhc app create newappname python-2.7
$ rhc cartridge add postgresql-9.2 -a newappname
```

Take note of the Git URL returned after the `app create` command.

```
$ git remote add newapptest GIT_URL
$ git push newapptest --force
$ open http://newapptest-mydomain.rhcloud.com
```

Et voila! It worked.

Since this was a mere hobby project with no important data in the
database, I went ahead and deleted it through the web interface, and
re ran the above commands replacing `newappname` with `originalappname`
and instead of adding it as a new `git remote` I updated remote pointing
to the now old-original/now-deleted app.

```
$ git remote set-url openshift GIT_URL
```

(**Note**: All the data in the database is deleted with the app, so if
the data is valuable start with a pg_dump and end with a pg_restore)

And my original URL is once again responding. I'm pretty sure it was something to do with Openshift's own settings, perhaps DNS or the like.

Comment: My OpenShift app is [a personal website that I can't change the domain of since it's indexed by Google](https://personalwebsite-noblehmushtak.rhcloud.com/), so do you know of anyway to fix this problem without creating a new app?

Answer (score 0):

Start with 'rhc app-force-stop '. Then restart it. Then watch logs when crashes again.

Comment: Please see edit on question to see my app's log when doing this. It did give some more info, but I'm not sure what to do with it. Also, on a hunch, I tried doing a DNS trace on my app URL and it gave an odd result.

Comment: Are you using any version control software such as git? If so revert back to a version that was known to work and deploy again to see if you created the problem. Unfortunately I have been in your situation and wasted many days only to find out if was an OPENSHIFT problem that had to be fixed by them. Very painful process.  It seems like django app configuration problem tho.

Comment: I am using git, but as I said, it didn't stop working in connection with a push. It worked after my last push, then at some point up to a week later, it stopped working.

Comment: Typically an app restart would fix an issue like this at least temporarily. Could it be a memory issue? Have you used up your gear allowance? Maybe try starting fresh and create new app and do a new push. As crazy as it sounds I have had to do this in the past on OPENSHIFT.  They have changed things on me a couple of times.

Comment: So to make it all clear, I tried creating a new account and a new app uploading the same code - and it works fine. So this isn't a code issue. I can't accept this as a 'resolution' it's a workaround at most.

Comment: LOL. I'm glad you got somewhere. We're you able to check your memory usage?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65056/discussion-between-davur-and-fat-fantasma).